# Trig identity $\sin(x)\cos(x) = \sin(2x)/2$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, volume

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TICylindricalCoords_files/eq0014MP.gif

Could someone tell me how $\sin(2x)$ arrives?

I know that there is a trig identity that says $2\cos(x)\sin(x) = \sin(2x)$ ... but this isn't isn't the case here... so could someone explain why?

Comment: Since you already know $2\cos(x)\sin(x)=\sin(2x)$, the desired identity follows by dividing both sides by $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that:

$$\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\sin b\cos a$$

Since $2x = x+x$ we have:

$$\sin(2x)=\sin(x+x)=\sin x\cos x+\sin x\cos x=2\sin x\cos x$$

Now this simplifies to $\sin x\cos x = \sin(2x)/2$ as you want.

Comment: Ahh.. i got it :D

Answer (score 0):

Using de Moivre's theorem:
$$
e^{nxi}=(\cos{x}+i\sin{x})^n = \cos{2x}+i\sin{2x}
$$

We expand the brackets and take the imaginary part (which is always $\sin(nx)i$):
$$
e^{2ix}=(\cos{x}+i\sin{x})^2=\cos^2{x}+2i\cos{x}\sin{x}-\sin^2{x} \\
\text{Im}(e^{2ix})=2\cos{x}\sin{x}=\sin{2x}
$$

---

Bonus: If we take the real part, we get an identity for $\cos{2x}$:
$$
\text{Re}(e^{2ix}) = \cos{2x} = \cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}
$$